# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

i am getting the below error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') in react
data is not coming from the Products.
i am learning the react now and this is my first project so could you please help to sort out this issue.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Products from "./Components/Products/Products";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Products />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Products.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import Product from "./Product/Product";

const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Macbook Air",
    description: "Apple Macbook Air",
    price: "$999",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Macbook Pro",
    description: "Apple Macbook Pro",
    price: "$1199",
  },
];

const Products = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

Product.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Card,
  CardMedia,
  CardContent,
  CardActions,
  Typography,
  IconButton,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { AddShoppingCart } from "@material-ui/icons";
import useStyles from "./styles";

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardMedia className={classes.media} image="" title={product.name} />
      <CardContent>
        <div className={classes.cardContent}>
          <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
            {product.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h5">{product.price}</Typography>
        </div>
        <Typography variant="h2" color="textSecondary">
          {product.description}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
        <IconButton aria-label="Add to cart">
          <AddShoppingCart />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

How can i solve the above problem
For reference please find the attached image
[image]

Comment: Your error in the console shows `products.name` (plural) but the code you've shared is `product` (singular). Which one is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't pass the `product` prop to your `<Product/>` component, so it's `undefined` by default, and then you're referencing the property `name` in the `Product` component of an undefined prop, therefore you get the error.

Make the following change

```js
const Products = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product product={product}/>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </main>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5):

It appears you are not passing the `product` as a prop to you `<Product />` component.

Add this to your map:

```
{products.map((product) => (
    <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
       <Product product={product}/>
    </Grid>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

need to pass prop to your component

```
{products.map((product) => (
<Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
   <Product product={product}/>
</Grid>
```

))}